# Animated Placeholder Image for AsyncTask with Additional Variable

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I am using the code from a [Android Developers Blog Post](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html) to asynchronusly load images into a RecyclerView. I now have the problem that I would like to display an Animation while it is loading. Unfortunately AnimatedVectorDrawable and AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat cannot be extended like it is done in the post because all constructors are private. [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) also is no option for me because it does not support animated placholders. 
Are the any other clean ways to do this? I would prefer Answers with a few more lines of code that do not need an external depency.
**Edit:**
I  now have this class as a placeholder:

```
static class DownloadedDrawable extends ColorDrawable
{
    private final WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderTask> bitmapDownloaderTaskReference;

    public DownloadedDrawable(BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask)
    {
        super(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        bitmapDownloaderTaskReference = new WeakReference<>(bitmapDownloaderTask);
    }

    public BitmapDownloaderTask getBitmapDownloaderTask()
    {
        return bitmapDownloaderTaskReference.get();
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(downloadedDrawable);
```

What I want to get is something that has the same function like this (if it worked) which I can use in the same way like the Placeholder I am using now:

```
static class AnimatedDownloadedDrawable extends AnimatedVectorDrawable
{
    private final WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderTask> bitmapDownloaderTaskReference;

    public AnimatedDownloadedDrawable(BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask)
    {
        super(R.drawable.myAnimation);
        bitmapDownloaderTaskReference = new WeakReference<>(bitmapDownloaderTask);
    }

    public BitmapDownloaderTask getBitmapDownloaderTask()
    {
        return bitmapDownloaderTaskReference.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's exactly the problem you are having with making an  animated place holder? You don't need any library to do this and you don't need to extend the `VectorDrawable` classes to create an animated vector drawable. You just need to define the drawable and animation in xml.

Comment: I have done that and the Animation itself is working.
They are using a custom class which holds a refernce to the task the BitmapDownloaderTask it was created by. This is the point we I am stuck. I fail to create a class that extends an Animatable Drawable to hold the extra Reference to the Task.